# Change Order Number and Invoice Number

Tags: orders, sales-order, invoice, magento-2.1.7

I am using Magento-2.1.7 and I want to change order, invoice and shipment number from 10000001 to 20000000.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Please perform following.

1. Open your PHP Admin database
2. Find & click on the table called: sequence_order_1 
   (it is located in database itself not in the information_schema )
3. Click on "Operations" tab & under "AUTO_INCREMENT" edit to desired order number.

You can do same for shipment and invoice tables `sequence_invoice_1` and `sequence_shipment_1`

**EDIT** To change digits length.

Change The Sequence
To change the order number padding edit Sequence.php 
(I believe there is a better way via a di.xml)

```
vendor/magento/module-sales-sequence/Model/Sequence.php
```

Edit this line

```
const DEFAULT_PATTERN  = "%s%'.09d%s";
```

Change the "9"  to the desired padding

Example

```
const DEFAULT_PATTERN  = "%s%'.08d%s";
```

Comment: How could I change the number of digits as Magento uses 9 while I want to use 8 digits?

Comment: @RishabhRkRai  I edited answer. Please check.

Comment: Instead of 9, you can use 8.

Comment: I make changes in the code, but still it shows 9 digits.

Comment: Please try clearing cache and removing var folder of your magento.

Comment: See here https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74908/discussion-between-kishan-patadia-and-rishabh-rk-rai).

Answer (score 0):

I want to just change padding to invoice number not to order number ! its there any way to do that?
as per mentioned above did that but it changed both invoice number as well order number